# aIs anonymous namespace structure unique

Tags: c++

I think I understood that anonymous namespace can be used to make the symbols local to current translation unit. But what about structure definitions, can I assume that they do refer to the same type ?

MyClass.h:

```cpp
namespace {
  class MyClass {};
}
```

A.h:

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

class A {
    MyClass* impl;
    void op();
}
```

A.cpp translation unit 1:

```cpp
#include "A.h"
void A::op() {
  // Let *this->impl refer to a type X.
}
```

B.cpp translation unit 2:

```cpp
#include "A.h"
void global_op(const A& a) {
  // Can I assume that *a->impl refer to same type X ?
}
```

Comment: In `B.cpp`, `A` is not defined. Please post the exact code you want to ask about (use different code blocks for different files)

Comment: There is still no C here. You mean just that "MyClass.h" is written in a C-like way?

Comment: @aschepler Seems to be fine considering C is no longer mentioned in the question.

Comment: @aschepler Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not refer to the same type. The header `MyClass.h` contains a definition of a class type `MyClass` inside an unnamed namespace. An unnamed namespace basically makes everything inside it (yes, types too) have internal linkage [[basic.link]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#6). You have two translation units, each (indirectly) includes `MyClass.h`, each gets it's own unnamed namespace with it's own `MyClass` [[basic.link]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11).

Think of an unnamed namespace as being a namespace that has a distinct name for each translation unit. So the `MyClass` in translation unit A is actually `$somerandomstringA$::MyClass`, while the `MyClass` in translation unit B is actually `$somerandomstringB$::MyClass`…

As discussed down in the comments to this answer, be aware of the fact that the program you described above will contain an ODR violation (specifically [[basic.def.odr]/12.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.2)) as a result of your class `A` being defined to contain a member of type `MyClass*`, which has a different meaning in different translation units.

Comment: Would this then mean that `class A` - which does refer to the same type in each TU - violates ODR, since each definition of `A` has a member of a different type?

Comment: @eerorika yes, it does. At least according to my understanding…

Comment: @eerorika specifically, it should violate [\[basic.def.odr\]/12.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.2). I believe to actually have seen compilers (clang) warn in situations that would necessarily lead to this kind of violation, but I can't remember a specific example right now…

Comment: I think it would be quite hard for a compiler to prove a violation, as TU's are usually compiled individually and this rule can only be violated when there are separate TU's involved. Maybe it is possible with modules... In any case, I agree with your understanding; It would be good to add a word of warning to the answer.

Comment: @eerorika indeed. Added that to my answer. Also, I think I remember now that the kind of warning I was reminded of before had to do with a missing definition for an entity with internal linkage, where the compiler would warn that this definition couldn't possibly be provided somewhere else; so not really related to what we were talking about here…

Answer (score 0):

This program has undefined behavior, since each translation unit defines `class ::A` but with two different meanings.

An anonymous namespace has internal linkage ([[basic.link]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#4)). The type `MyClass` has the same linkage as its namespace, so also internal linkage ([[basic.link]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#4.3)). And internal linkage means that the type can only be named from the same translation units, so the two translation units formed from A.cpp and B.cpp define two different types named `MyClass`.  This isn't a problem, yet.

But the global namespace and class `A` have external linkage.  There are two definitions of the single type `::A`, but they give the member `impl` two different types.  This is a One Definition Rule violation.

(Although we often say "the ODR", there are really essentially two flavors: [[basic.def.odr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#10) applies to things like objects and functions which are namespace members and not marked `inline`, and says the program can only have one definition, in one TU; so we usually put those in source files. [[basic.def.odr]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#12) applies to things like types, things marked `inline`, and declarations with template parameters, and says multiple TUs may each have one definition, but all must have the same token spelling (after preprocessing) and the same meaning; so we often put those in header files so that multiple TUs can use a common definition.)

Specifically here, the program violates [[basic.def.odr]/12.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#12.2):

> There can be more than one definition of a class type, ... in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - ...; and
> - in each definition of `D`, corresponding names, looked up according to [basic.lookup], shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of `D`, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution and after matching of partial template specialization ([temp.over]), except that a name can refer to
>
>   - a non-volatile const object with internal or no linkage if ..., or
>   - a reference with internal or no linkage initialized with a constant expression such that ...;
>
> and ....
>
> ... If the definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

Here `MyClass` is a name within the definitions of `class ::A` but referring to two different entities, and not falling into any of the specifically permitted categories.

This might work in practice for many systems, since both translation units will see the same member names, types, and offsets within their own `MyClass` types.  But if `MyClass` ever ends up being used in "name mangling", that will go wrong.  And anyway, it's safest to avoid undefined behavior whenever you can.